# Mathematical rule for choosing X & Y for scatterplot maximising spread of points

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, scatterplot

Is there any method for choosing a combination of X and Y dimensions for a scatterplot, from a larger dataset that has been standardized to be centered at zero and have unit variance, that will maximize the spread of points ?

Comment: Perhaps the solution you're after is using hexagonal binning https://datavizproject.com/data-type/hexagonal-binning/

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "spread of points" and how would like it to be measured?  Indeed, in a large dataset (or any dataset) what constitutes a "point:" an actual vector of values or, for instance, could it be a linear combination of values?

Comment: So that the Euclidean distance between the coordinates of the scatterplot made from any combination of columns is greatest.

Comment: That distance isn't usually visually evident in a scatterplot.  It would depend on what exactly you mean by a "normalized" dataset.  If you mean the columns have been *standardized* to be centered at zero and have unit variance, then since in that case the Euclidean distance is inversely related to the correlation coefficient, you seek a pair of *minimally* (*i.e.* most negatively) correlated variables. Regardless, there's no help for it short of computing all pairs of distances (or correlations) and selecting the largest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you answered your own question - after normalization, take the columns with the largest euclidean distance.

That being said, not sure what inference you are trying to glean from this. Typically, we look for columns with high correlation (or maybe lack of correlation in your case) or we can use principal components analysis to find the latent dimensions that explain the most variance in our data. Other measures I can think of off hand may be entropy or [conductance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conductance_(graph))